# Ajax Drupal detect uploaded image too large

Tags: php, ajax, apache, nginx, drupal

I'm trying to solve a problem on a content (agenda) creation form which needs two images uploaded by the admin. The problem is when we create the content for the first time and try to upload the images, we got in the console a Drupal Ajax error which prevents the form to be correctly submitted.

The error:
[image]

When I visit the page that contains the debugging information it says that the uploaded file exceed the maximum file size allowed by the server (40 MB) although I uploaded a 100 KB image.

In the content type of my agenda, both my images fields have the 40 MB limit set up and same for my php.ini upload_max_filesize is set to 40 MB

I have confirmed that this error can be reproduced on different environments (Windows + Xampp and Linux + Nginx)

I ran out of ideas, so if everyone has any ideas on how to fix this, I would appreciate ^^.

Comment: hi, did you setup the public folder/path?

Comment: @benzo Hello, thanks for  your answer, what do you mean by that ?

Comment: What are values of post_max_size and memory_limit set in php.ini ?

Comment: @MilanG Hello, thanks for you answer, post_max_size is 40M and memory_limit is 512M

Answer (score 0):

In your Nginx server config try something like:

```
server {

    client_max_body_size      40M;
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, this is alredy done.